# Installing Anaconda on Linux VM Instance on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python-3.x, linux, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I have provisioned a VM (ubuntu-minimal-1804) on google cloud platform. I want to install anaconda3 and run jupyter notebooks on it. I lack the Computer Science/ IT background and hence tried to follow the online resources. I am finding it difficult install the anaconda3 and jupyter on the VM despite following these sources. Can anyone help me with this? I would really appreciate if anyone can provide me with step-by-step guide.
Note: These are the links that I followed but failed to install anaconda

1. https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-google-cloud/
2. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/google-cloud-data-science

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your link shows a very simple installation. Show what you have done (steps) and the problem. Start with this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The [steps](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-google-cloud/) that you have followed should be applicable to your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM (with the official image and default setup), after locating it in your [instances list](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) and clicking on the **SSH** button.

Despite the "minimal" images lacking some of the commonly-used utilities in Ubuntu, I could test the commands in the [guide](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-google-cloud/) in a new VM from the ubuntu-minimal-1804-lts image family and managed to successfully install Anaconda3, except for the VSCode installation that seemed to have an outdated server connection check.

I would also recommend trying the latest installer for Anaconda3 that's available in the [repo archive](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) instead, as the one in the [guide](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-google-cloud/) is a bit outdated:

```
$ curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ rm -rf ~/anaconda3  # (clear previous attempted installation first, if any)
$ bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

In any case, as suggested by [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720), feel free to comment below or edit your question with any errors that you might get.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It kind of worked but the file uploading on the subsequent VM did not work. So, I left any hopes of using Cloud Computing power for my large dataset. Thank you so much for the help.